# VIDIOC_S_FMT error 5 , Input/output error

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, camera, usb-cam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
When i run the node usb_cam in ros kinetic under ubuntu 16.04 I have this error:

```
[ERROR] [1555322281.131759362]: VIDIOC_S_FMT error 5, Input/output error
[usb_cam-2] process has died [pid 18567, exit code 1, cmd /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/usb_cam/usb_cam_node __name:=usb_cam __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/f0d32396-5f64-11e9-a083-b06ebfbf3825/usb_cam-2.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/f0d32396-5f64-11e9-a083-b06ebfbf3825/usb_cam-2*.log
```

When I unplug the camera then re-plug it works just once then i have the same erros.
help me please

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321113/vidioc_s_fmt-error-5-,-input/output-error/) by [nana](https://answers.ros.org/users/37385/nana/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-04-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nana](https://answers.ros.org/users/37385/nana/) on 2019-04-25**:
Any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rebooting the computer after installing usb_cam and apt updating worked for me. Initially, running `v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext` only returned a list of some of the possible formats.

---

Originally posted by [Andrew Price](https://answers.ros.org/users/3629/andrew-price/) with karma: 66 on 2019-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0